# APS.NET core web API redirect with response data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1, http-redirect

I'm using asp.net core 3.1 and I have a web API endpoint wherein I have to redirect with the response(session) data, currently, we have an old framework with HTTPHandler that is handling redirection with session data however how to achieve the same using web API?

I tried with sample code, but it returns response message, I want to have something like `new RedirectResult("google.com");`

```
private HttpResponseMessage Verify(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    ...

    return actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Redirect, "json session data");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it two possible ways, maybe more. But here is an example that has 2 ways. You can add your json session data to the header and have the person receiving the response look it up. Or just simple dump it into the content (which is what I would do), and they can just read it as the content returned.

Example:

```cs
public HttpResponseMessage Verify()
{
    try
    {
        var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Redirect);
                    
        response.Headers.Location = new Uri("google.com");
        response.Headers.Add("JsonSessiondata", "json session data");
    
        //or
    
        response.Content = new StringContent("json session data");
                    
        //Can do this too
        //response.Content = new ObjectContent<T>(T, myFormatter, "application/some-format");

        return response;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Was typing out something like this also. I'd just put it in the content too.

Comment: @mathis1337 Thanks for the answer, so basically this will return a 200OK response with the content and the client needs to take care of redirecting? Is it possible to redirect to a page directly with all the session details?

Comment: @TravTanker I would like to hear your version too, please

Comment: No this will return a 302 redirect per the response message. Redirect
302
Equivalent to HTTP status 302. Redirect indicates that the requested information is located at the URI specified in the Location header. The default action when this status is received is to follow the Location header associated with the response. When the original request method was POST, the redirected request will use the GET method. Redirect is a synonym for Found.

Comment: So in my case the person receiving this response would follow my header location to Google.com

Comment: @mathis1337 Yes I got your point, however, I would like to redirect directly instead of client taking a call just think that this is an external URL, and before proceeding to the external URL, client needs to do some validation so it goes through this validate endpoint.

Comment: In short, I'm looking like this new RedirectResult("https://google.com"); but I cannot attach content.